In Unity Catalog, using PySpark, Is it possible to get 'Record Counts' of Multiple Tables (ideally using 1 command), in one dataframe, as done in SQL
I have multiple tables in Unity Catalog and I would like get record count of specified tables in one result. In SQL, we can easily do this, using following command:
%sql
Select * From (
    Select 'TableABC' as TableName, count(*) As RecordCount From CatalogName.SchemaName.TableABC
    Union All
    Select 'TableXYZ' as TableName, count(*) As RecordCount From CatalogName.SchemaName.TableXYZ
    Union All
    Select 'TableMNQ' as TableName, count(*) As RecordCount From CatalogName.SchemaName.TableMNQ
) a
Order By RecordCount Desc

Result:
---------------------------
TableName   |   RecordCount
---------------------------
TableMNQ    |   500
TableABC    |   300
TableXYZ    |   100

Want to achieve the same result set using PySpark, and if possible, using just 1 command like above.
Edited the Question, to specify that the table names are not in sequence like, Table1, Table2 etc. There are table with unique names and have no co-relation to any sequencing or ordering.

df = spark.sql('''
Select * From (
    Select 'Table1' as TableName, count(*) As RecordCount From CatalogName.SchemaName.Table1
    Union All
    Select 'Table2' as TableName, count(*) As RecordCount From CatalogName.SchemaName.Table2
    Union All
    Select 'Table3' as TableName, count(*) As RecordCount From CatalogName.SchemaName.Table3
) a
Order By RecordCount Desc
''')

df.show()

or
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[], schema='count(1): int')
for i in range(1,4):
  tn = f'Table{i}'
  df.unionAll(
     spark.table(tn).agg({'*': 'count'})
     .withColumnRenamed('count(1)', 'RecordCount')
     .withColumn(tn, F.lit('t1'))
  )

df.show()

OR
for i in range(1,4):
  tn = f'Table{i}'
  print(f'{tn}: {spark.table(tn).count()}')

